# Как мне вырезать изображение по форме этого изображения PNG в CSS?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, png

Как разместить изображение поверх этого изображения png, но сохранить форму в CSS?

Я видел, что есть способы сделать это с помощью `clipPath` SVG, но мне было интересно, есть ли более быстрый способ, просто установив его как фоновое изображение или что-то в этом роде?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How do I fit an image to the shape of this PNG image in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66736331/7394871) от участника  [@ryan.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14222059/ryan).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66736331/7394871

Answer (score 2):

это назначение работы `-webkit-mask`:

```css
img {
  -webkit-mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/mBrmH0k/Mf15d.png) center/contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1079/300/300">
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66736519/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>